# Django many foreign table queries despite `select_related`

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I'm trying to join A parent and 2 child tables in django.

I can see that each time a list view is run, there are 50 queries (the page size) executed on the `ChildB` table.  I thought that I could improve performance using the `select_related` method, but it seems not to be taken into account.

Using `prefetch_related` the behaviour is as expected.

Why is `select_related` not taken into account?

- [select_related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#select-related) for Django 2.2 (which I'm using)
- [prefetch_related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related)

Models:

```py
class Parent(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    uuid_a = models.ForeignKey(ChildA, db_column='uuid_a', db_index=True, default=None, editable=False, null=True,
                               on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, primary_key=False, related_name='result_suppliers', unique=True,)
    uuid_b = models.ForeignKey(ChildB, db_column='uuid_b', db_index=True, default=None, editable=False,
                               null=True, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, primary_key=False, related_name='duns_suppliers', unique=True,)


class ChildA(models.Model):
    # ss
    uuid = models.CharField(primary_key=True, editable=False, max_length=36, db_index=True)


class ChildB(models.Model):
    # sd
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, editable=False)
    duns_num = models.ForeignKey(ChildX, db_column='duns_num', to_field='duns_num', db_constraint=False, default=None, editable=False, null=True, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, primary_key=False, unique=False)
```

Serializers:

```py
class ChildAListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = ChildA
        fields = ['uuid', ]  # others


class ChildAListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = ChildB
        fields = ['uuid', 'duns_num']  # others


class ParentListSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    uuid_a = ChildAListSerializer()
    uuid_b = ChildBListSerializer()
    last_sync = serializers.DateTimeField()
    # others

    class Meta:
        model = Parent
        fields = '__all__'
```

view:

```py
class ParentListView(ListAPIView):
    """
    List view for deduplication suppliers screen
    """
    filter_backends = [filters.DjangoFilterBackend]
    filterset_class = DeduplicationParentFilter
    pagination_class = LimitOffsetPagination
    page_size = 30
    max_page_size = 30

    pk_field = 'id'  # Name of the primaryKey to use for counting
    fk_fields = ['uuid_a', 'uuid_b']  # Name of the foreignKey to prefetch on request
    model = Parent
    serializer_class = ParentListSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Parent.objects.select_related(*self.fk_fields)

    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        queryset = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset())
        result = {}
    
        # Paginate response
        page = self.paginate_queryset(queryset)

        if page is not None:
            # We can paginate, serialize page
            serializer = self.get_serializer(page, many=True)
            result['data'] = serializer.data
            response = self.get_paginated_response(result)

        else:
            # We cant, serializer queryset
            serializer = self.get_serializer(queryset, many=True)
            result['data'] = serializer.data
            response = JsonResponse(result)
        return response
```

Comment: Do you have other foreign keys in the ChildA and ChildB models? Add your full serializers and models if you can, maybe you need to add more values to your fk_fields.

Comment: I'd rather not make the question too long (so I'll hold off adding the fill serializers, as theyre big) but you think that adding other fields would help @gdef_?

Comment: If for example your ChildA model has a FK to another model named let's say "model_c", then you need to add that also to the select related. Like `uuid_a__model_c`. Also I recommend using `django_debug_toolbar` to help debug your queries.

Comment: @gdef_my god it works.  Thank you so much.  I will update the question, can you post an answer please?  I will accept asap.  Thank you again!

Comment: Sure, I have added the answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a foreign key in your `ChildB` model that is causing the extra queries because you are using it in that model serializer. You need to add it to `fk_fields`. You follow the relations using `__` like with normal orm queries.

```
fk_fields = ['uuid_a', 'uuid_b', 'uuid_b__duns_num']
```